# Can I advertise my work on a site's meta?

Tags: discussion, spam, per-site-meta, self-promotion

Let's say I write Microsoft Word. Can I advertise it on Writing Meta?

Posting it on chat is absolutely fine, but I think it is hard to format the post properly, to explain why it is interesting, and to have a place to incubate ideas and feedback. The ideas are complex, so chat is a bad place to do it. Viewing myself as genuine, I don't see how it is different between posting my own work and other's work.

In general, if a work doesn't improve the site, but may be interesting to the people of that site, then can it be posted?

Comment: In general, no.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's see what a [typical meta is for](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> - **...Writing Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other** about Writing Stack Exchange (asking questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions)
> - **...Writing Stack Exchange users to communicate with Stack Overflow the company** (posting bugs, suggesting improvements, or proposing new features), and
> - **...Stack Overflow the company to communicate with the community** (soliciting feedback on new ideas or features, or discussing policies that affect the whole network)

So unless it's something that is directly related to the website (e.g. if Word would have a plugin which converts a Word document to markdown which is directly pasteable into a Stack Exchange post), it's off-topic.

> to have a place to incubate ideas and feedback.

This sounds rather broad for a single Q&A, too.

---

Of course, if you can demonstrate how your product solves a question on the main site, and you include affiliation, it's fine to post about it. This happens frequently on Software Recommendations, and also from time to time on the programming sites with libraries being 'promoted' by their authors. If done on the right question and it's genuinely a good solution, it's a win-win situation for all.

Otherwise, consider writing a paragraph about it in your profile, together with a 'read more' link.

Comment: I think meta can be a place to incubate ideas and feedback

Comment: Sure, *about the site/community itself* ...

Answer (score 7):

From the [help-center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/behavior):

> **Avoid overt self-promotion.**
>
> The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers.
>
> If a large percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source projects and non-profit organizations.

This piece of help-center should be the same across most communities. Given that, the statement you made about not improving the site, and the fact that meta sites have spam flags just like main sites, **this sounds like a general bad idea.**

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can *absolutely* advertise on any SE site.  To do so use the [contact form](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) to get in touch with the company (there's an option in the form specifically to discuss advertising with them) and see their rates and conditions for advertisements.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you a advertise on a site besides Stack Overflow? So far I only know about community ad

Comment: @Ooker Yes, you buy ads [here](https://www.selfserve-stackexchange.com/), which lists all the options. But the selection is almost entirely all technology sites (and it doesn't include Writing).